Unable to load List.js accurately while loading data using AJAX
I'm working on a pagination feature using List.js for my email page on a website where emails are loaded using PHP, MySQL, and AJAX. I have installed List.js locally and referenced it correctly in my footer. While the pagination works fine on other pages, it's not functioning correctly on my emails page.
Here’s a brief overview of the setup:
Page Loading: When the user navigates to the email page, email.php loads. I’ve added a PHP condition to load email_inbox.php by default inside email.php unless the user selects another option (e.g., sent, draft, trash). In that case, email.php dynamically loads the selected content.
Issue Description: The problem is that when the page loads, the emails are displayed with pagination for a brief moment, and then all the emails appear without pagination.
NOTE: I have tested the email_inbox.php code in a separate file, and it loaded the emails with pagination correctly.
Here’s a simplified version of my code to illustrate the issue:

email_inbox.php

<?php
if (empty($emails)) {
    echo "<div class='text-center'>No emails found</div>";
} else { ?>
    <div id='all-emails' data-list='{"valueNames":["email"],"page":5,"pagination":true}'>

        <div class='list' id='emails-list'>
            <?php
            foreach ($emails as $email) {
                $id = $email['id'];
                $sender = $email['sender'];
                $sender_name = $email['sender_name'];
                $cc_recipient = $email['cc_recipient'];
                $bcc_recipient = $email['bcc_recipient'];
                $subject = $email['subject'];
                $content = $email['content'];
                $content = str_replace("\xC2\xA0", ' ', $content);
                $is_read = $email['is_read'];
                $is_starred = $email['is_starred'];
                $is_archived = $email['is_archived'];
                $is_deleted = $email['is_deleted'];
                $is_draft = $email['is_draft'];
                $is_interview = $email['is_interview'];
                $is_application_received = $email['is_application_received'];
                $is_not_accepted = $email['is_not_accepted'];
                $is_job_ad = $email['is_job_ad'];
                $is_skill_test = $email['is_skill_test'];
                $timeZone = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Karachi');
                $created_at = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $email['created_at'], $timeZone);
                $sent_at = $email['sent_at'];
                $updated_at = $email['updated_at'];
                $attachments = $email['attachments'];

                // Calculate the time difference
                $currentDate = new DateTime();
                $timeDifference = $currentDate->diff($created_at);
                // Determine the most appropriate unit
                if ($timeDifference->days == 0) {
                    if ($timeDifference->h == 0) {
                        if ($timeDifference->i == 0) {
                            $timeAgo = $timeDifference->s . 's';
                        } else {
                            $timeAgo = $timeDifference->i . 'm';
                        }
                    } else {
                        $timeAgo = $timeDifference->h . 'h';
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($timeDifference->y > 0) {
                        $timeAgo = $timeDifference->y . 'Y';
                    } elseif ($timeDifference->m > 0) {
                        $timeAgo = $timeDifference->m . 'M';
                    } else {
                        $timeAgo = $timeDifference->d . 'D';
                    }
                }
            ?>

                <div class="email border-top border-translucent hover-actions-trigger py-3 <?php echo $is_read == 0 ? 'bg-white' : ''; ?>" id="email-item" data-email-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-email-read="<?php echo $is_read; ?>">
                    <div class="row align-items-center gx-2">
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row">
                                <button class="btn p-0 star-btn" data-email-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-email-folder="inbox" data-email-starred="<?php echo $is_starred; ?>">
                                    <span class="<?php echo $is_starred ? "fas" : "far"; ?> text-body-quaternary fa-star"></span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <a class="text-body-emphasis fw-bold inbox-link fs-9 email-items email-links" href="email.php?folder=details" data-folder="details" data-email-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-current-folder="inbox">
                                <?php
                                if (empty($sender_name)) {
                                    echo $sender;
                                } else {
                                    echo $sender_name;
                                }
                                ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto ms-auto">
                            <div class="hover-actions end-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-phoenix-secondary btn-icon dropdown-toggle dropdown-caret-none" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-boundary="window" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-bs-reference="parent">
                                    <span class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis"></span>
                                </button>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end py-2">
                                    <?php if ($_SESSION['role'] === 'candidate') : ?>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#kanbanAddTask" href="javascript:void(0);">Mark Interview</a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                    <a class="dropdown-item archive-btn" data-email-folder="inbox" data-email-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" href="javascript:void(0);" data-email-archived="<?php echo $is_archived; ?>">Archive</a>

                                    <a class="dropdown-item interview-btn" data-email-folder="inbox" data-email-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" href="javascript:void(0);" data-email-interview="<?php echo $is_interview; ?>">Move to
                                        Interviews</a>

                                    <a class="dropdown-item application-received-btn" data-email-folder="inbox" data-email-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" href="javascript:void(0);" data-email-application-received="<?php echo $is_application_received; ?>">Move to
                                        Application Received</a>

                                    <a class="dropdown-item not-accepted-btn" data-email-folder="inbox" data-email-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" href="javascript:void(0);" data-email-not-accepted="<?php echo $is_not_accepted; ?>">Move to
                                        Not Accepted</a>

                                    <a class="dropdown-item job-ad-btn" data-email-folder="inbox" data-email-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" href="javascript:void(0);" data-email-job-ad="<?php echo $is_job_ad; ?>">Move to
                                        Job Ads</a>

                                    <a class="dropdown-item skill-test-btn" data-email-folder="inbox" data-email-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" href="javascript:void(0);" data-email-skill-test="<?php echo $is_skill_test; ?>">Move to
                                        Skill Test Assessments</a>

                                    <a class="dropdown-item text-danger" id="delete-email" data-email-deleted="<?php echo $is_deleted; ?>" data-email-folder="inbox" data-email-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <span class="fs-10 fw-bold"><?php echo $timeAgo; ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ms-4 mt-sm-0">
                        <a class="d-block inbox-link email-items email-links" href="email.php?folder=details" data-folder="details" data-email-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-current-folder="inbox">
                            <span class="fs-9 line-clamp-1 text-body-emphasis"><?php echo $subject; ?></span>
                            <p class="fs-9 ps-0 text-body-tertiary mb-0 line-clamp-2">
                                <?php
                                $doc = new DOMDocument();
                                libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
                                $doc->loadHTML($content);
                                libxml_clear_errors();

                                removeElementsByTagName('script', $doc);
                                removeElementsByTagName('style', $doc);
                                removeElementsByTagName('link', $doc);

                                $textContent = strip_tags($doc->saveHTML());

                                $maxLength = 100;
                                if (strlen($textContent) > $maxLength) {
                                    $plainContent = substr($textContent, 0, $maxLength) . '...';
                                }

                                echo $plainContent;
                                ?>
                            </p>
                        </a>

                        <?php
                        if (!empty($attachments)) {
                            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                                $filename = $attachment['file_name'] ?: $attachment['file_address'];
                                $fileExtension = strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                                $iconClass = getIconClass($fileExtension);
                        ?>

                                <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center border border-translucent rounded-pill px-3 py-1 me-2 mt-2 inbox-link" href="queries/download_attachments.query.php?file_url=<?php echo $attachment['file_address']; ?>" download>
                                    <span class="<?php echo $iconClass; ?> fs-9"></span>
                                    <span class="ms-2 fw-bold fs-10 text-body"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($filename); ?></span>
                                </a>

                        <?php
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <?php
            } ?>

        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-between py-2 pe-0 fs-9">
            <div class="col-auto d-flex">
                <p class="mb-0 d-none d-sm-block me-3 fw-semibold text-body" data-list-info="data-list-info">
                </p>
                <a class="fw-semibold" href="#!" data-list-view="*">
                    View all<span class="fas fa-angle-right ms-1" data-fa-transform="down-1"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="fw-semibold d-none" href="#!" data-list-view="less">
                    View Less<span class="fas fa-angle-right ms-1" data-fa-transform="down-1"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto d-flex">
                <button class="page-link" data-list-pagination="prev">
                    <span class="fas fa-chevron-left"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="mb-0 pagination"></ul>
                <button class="page-link pe-0" data-list-pagination="next">
                    <span class="fas fa-chevron-right"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>


email.php

<div id="load-folder-emails">
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['folder'])) {
        $folder = $_GET['folder'];
        if (isset($_GET['emailId'])) {
            $emailId = $_GET['emailId'];
        }
        if (isset($_GET['currentFolder'])) {
            $currentFolder = $_GET['currentFolder'];
        }
    } else {
        $folder = 'inbox';
    }

    if ($folder == 'inbox') {
        include_once 'email_inbox.php';
    } else if ($folder == 'sent') {
        include_once 'email_sent.php';
    } else if ($folder == 'draft') {
        include_once 'email_draft.php';
    } else if ($folder == 'spam') {
        include_once 'email_spam.php';
    } else if ($folder == 'deleted') {
        include_once 'email_deleted.php';
    } else if ($folder == 'starred') {
        include_once 'email_starred.php';
    } else if ($folder == 'archived') {
        include_once 'email_archived.php';
    } else if ($folder == 'details') {
        include_once 'email_details.php';
    } else if ($folder == 'interviews') {
        include_once 'email_interviews.php';
    } else if ($folder == 'applicationReceived') {
        include_once 'email_application_received.php';
    } else if ($folder == 'notAccepted') {
        include_once 'email_not_accepted.php';
    } else if ($folder == 'jobAds') {
        include_once 'email_job_ads.php';
    } else if ($folder == 'skillTestAssessments') {
        include_once 'email_skill_assessment.php';
    }
    ?>
</div>


footer.inc.php

<script>
  function setActiveClass(folder) {
    $('.vertical-nav .nav-link').removeClass('active');
    $('.vertical-nav .nav-link[data-folder="' + folder + '"]').addClass('active');
  }

  function getQueryParameter(name) {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    return urlParams.get(name);
  }

  function loadFolderContent(folder, emailId, currentFolder) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'email.php',
      type: 'GET',
      data: { folder: folder, emailId: emailId, currentFolder: currentFolder },
      success: function (response) {
        $('#load-folder-emails').html($(response).find('#load-folder-emails').html());
        setActiveClass(folder);
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {
    var folder = getQueryParameter('folder') || 'inbox';
    var emailId = getQueryParameter('emailId') || '';
    var currentFolder = getQueryParameter('currentFolder') || '';

    if (folder == 'compose') {
      $('.vertical-nav .nav-link').removeClass('active');
      $('#load-folder-emails').hide();
      $('#compose-email-container').show();
    } else {
      loadFolderContent(folder, emailId, currentFolder);
      $('#load-folder-emails').show();
      $('#compose-email-container').hide();
    }

    $('body').on('click', '.email-links', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var folder = $(this).data('folder');
      var emailId = '';
      var currentFolder = '';

      if (folder == 'details') {

        var emailId = $(this).data('email-id');
        var currentFolder = $(this).data('current-folder');

        loadFolderContent(folder, emailId, currentFolder);

        $('#load-folder-emails').show();
        $('#compose-email-container').hide();

      } else if (folder == 'compose') {

        $('.vertical-nav .nav-link').removeClass('active');
        $('#load-folder-emails').hide();
        $('#compose-email-container').show();

      } else {

        setActiveClass(folder);
        loadFolderContent(folder, emailId, currentFolder);

        $('#load-folder-emails').show();
        $('#compose-email-container').hide();

      }

      // Update the URL without reloading the page
      var newUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?folder=' + folder;
      if (emailId) {
        newUrl += '&emailId=' + emailId + '&currentFolder=' + currentFolder;
      }

      window.history.pushState({ path: newUrl }, '', newUrl);
    });
  });

  // Handle back/forward navigation
  window.onpopstate = function (event) {
    var folder = getQueryParameter('folder') || 'inbox';
    var emailId = getQueryParameter('emailId') || '';
    var currentFolder = getQueryParameter('currentFolder') || '';
    loadFolderContent(folder, emailId, currentFolder);
  };
</script>

What I have done already: Other lists are auto-initialized and working fine, though I tried to initialize this list manually, but it didn't work.

Since you mention that your email are rendered correctly and then after the page has loaded the error occurs, I'd suspect that something with the JS goes wrong. Did you have a look into the console and - if so - does it say something? For debugging purposes, it would also help if you could post the generated HTML, CSS & JS as an MRE so that we can debug it.

@Davi I haven't seen anything in console related to this issue.

Post the JS part.

@Gabriel I have updated my question and added JS part in it, please check.
